# very important interface need help

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-deployment, fallback-function, function

the balance not change from another contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;


interface ICounter {
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external view returns (bool);
    function balances(address owner) external returns (uint);
}

contract MyContract {
    uint public theBalance;
    function incrementCounter(address _counter,uint value) external {
        theBalance = ICounter(_counter).balances(msg.sender);
        theBalance = value;
    }

    function getCount(address _counter) external view returns (uint) {
        return ICounter(_counter).balanceOf(msg.sender);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, can you share all of smart contract code including interface and other contracts?

Comment: ICounter doesn't provide a method to modify its state. Both `balanceOf` and `transfer` are views so they won't change the contract state. And `balances` only accepts an address so there's no way to change the internal counter value.

Answer (score 0):

this another contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    uint public totalSupply = 120000000 * 10 ** 18;
    string public name = "Test";
    string public symbol = "TST";
    uint public decimals = 18;
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    
    constructor() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address owner) public returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
       emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[from] -= value;
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;   
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns (bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;   
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).